# Shutdown when Ubuntu One has synced

Tags: ubuntu-one, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [some programs are still running… is there anyway to auto delay the shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63574/some-programs-are-still-running-is-there-anyway-to-auto-delay-the-shutdown)

My Ubuntu One sometimes takes a while to sync when there's lots of data added to the folder. Rather than run my computer all night, is there a way of getting it to shut down once syncing is finished?